# Ran "network restart", netstat shows no open ports, server still says port is in use

Tags: linux, networking, port, opensuse

I am doing some web development in django (python). The program runs it's own development server on port 8000. I turned off the server and now need to restart it, but I'm getting an "Error: That port is already in use"

I did a `sudo /etc/init.d/network restart eth0` and the return was:

```
Shutting down network interfaces:
Setting up network interfaces:
    eth0      Startmode is 'manual' -> skipping                                               skipped
    eno16777736 device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
    eno16777736 DHCP4 client (dhcpcd) is running
    eno16777736 IP address: 192.168.163.128/24
    eno16777736 DHCP6 client (dhclient6) is running
    eno16777736 . . . but is still waiting for data
    eno16777736       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever IP address: 192.168.163.128/24
    eno16777736 is up                                                                         done
    lo        
    lo       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever IP address: 127.0.0.1/8
    lo        is up                                                                         done
```

and then running `sudo netstat -np | grep 8000` returns nothing. But when I try to run the server again it gives me the same error. Rebooting the machine completely fixes it, but I can't do this everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever this happens to me, I run `ps aux | grep ruby` and find the list of services that matches my criteria. In my case, I do Ruby on Rails development so I will use `grep ruby`.

[image]

Once I find my `PID` (second column), I execute the command `kill -9 PID`

[image]

This will kill the process and I can then restart my service using the same port.

Comment: Thanks, this works, and is very close to what I'm doing (i.e Python and Django)

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting the "-a" option to nestat. Otherwise with just "-np" it will just give you "non-listening" sockets (aka the sockets connected). So try with "-npa" eventually to be sure you're getting the complete data (both listening and non-listening).

That being said I'd suggest in case to do a:

> lsof | grep TCP | grep 8000

If you have lsof installed.

If the server is listening (or wants to listen) to all the network interfaces it may be still waiting on loopback device for example. So my suggestion is try with lsof as mentioned.